# set userID at signup in accounts collection firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to set a userID at signup in a collection called 'accounts'. That way 'accounts' will have a userID and displayName. However, this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
        // Sign up
// This part works
        try {
            setError("")
            setLoading(true)
            await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
                .then(function (result) {
                    return result.user.updateProfile({
                        displayName: displayNameRef.current.value
                    })
                })
//This doesnt work
            .then(function (cred) {
                return collectionRef.doc(cred.user.uid).set({
                    userID: currentUser.uid
                })
            })

            history.push("/")
```

Comment: If problem still exists message me on discussion.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in chaining promises. Try just copy and paste

```
try {
       setError("");
       setLoading(true);
       signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
          .then(function (result) {
              result.user.updateProfile({
                  displayName: displayNameRef.current.value
               })
               .then(function (cred) {
                   collectionRef.doc(cred.user.uid).set({
                   userID: currentUser.uid
                });
          });
       history.push("/")
     }
```